# Setting height of fancybox 2.1.4 iframe dynamically after contents finish rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

We have some jQuery graphs that load into a fancybox iframe. Recently, some of these graphs are too tall for the fancybox frame, and the design requirement is that there is no scroll bar unless the height is over 700px AND there is no more than 10px of whitespace above and below the graph.

I tried this:

```
afterLoad : function(){
    //(...)
    $('.fancybox-inner').height($('.fancybox-iframe').contents().height() + 20);
    console.log($('.fancybox-inner').height());
}
```

The `console.log()` correctly displays the desigred height.

But the fancybox is still displayed with the default height.

Putting a breakpoint on the `console.log()` line, the page displays the fancybox frame on the top of the window, graph rendered and iframe with the correct height. When I release the debugger stop, fancybox moves the frame to the center of the viewport, and it is back to the default height (the same behavior when not in debug mode).

How can I make fancybox use the desired height? It depends on the graph, so I cannot set it in the options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with iframes make things a bit difficult but you may try something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        fitToView: false, // we need this
        autoSize: false, // and this
        maxWidth: "95%", // and this too
        beforeShow: function () {
            // find the inner height of the iframe contents
            var _newHeight = $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("html").innerHeight();
            this.height = _newHeight
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we disable `fitToView` and `autoSize` to be able to set the preferred `height`, however we also need to set a `maxWidth` to avoid fancybox going off screen dimensions.

Also notice we used the `beforeShow` callback to set the `this.height` setting.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: Your fiddle used 2.1.5, but I updated the library in my project.